# How do you find the potential difference between 2 different resistors in series when there is an open switch

Tags: potential, voltage

I apologise that this is a very basic question.

I am trying to self learn the basics of electrical circuits and came across this question, [question 9 in this link](https://www.siyavula.com/read/science/grade-12/electric-circuits/10-electric-circuits-07).

I understand that potential difference means you have to subtract the voltage on either side of the resistor. However, which side do you subtract from which, and my bigger question here is:
The switch is open so shouldn't there be no voltage of any kind? According to the worked answer, the answer is C, 18V and 18V. However, I would have thought it was one of 2 answers, 1) it should be 0V for V1 since the switch is open, and 0V for V2, since there is a break in the circuit so it would be 0 anywhere.

However, since potential difference is about subtracting either side, then I can sort of understand it if it is 2) 0V for V1 with the same reason as above, then, for V2, it is 18V because on the right hand side of the open switch (or positive side), it should be 18V, then the circuit is broken so on the left hand side or negative side, it should be zero. Since we consider current to flow from positive to negative, then 18 - 0 is 18, and my final answer would have been 0 for V1 and 18 for V2. This approach is also wrong, it seems.

Would appreciate it if someone could explain.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> which side do you subtract from which,

Whichever ones you want.

If you want to know the potential difference between points *a* and *b* you take $V_a - V_b$. If you want to know the potential difference between *b* and *a* you $V_b-V_a$.

Really, the voltmeters in your problem statement should be labeled with one terminal as the "+" terminal and the other as the "-" terminal, so you know which voltage to subtract from which to find out what the meter will read. But since you're only given positive voltages to choose from among the answer choices, you can assume they're oriented whichever way results in a positive reading.

> The switch is open so shouldn't there be no voltage of any kind?

An ideal open circuit can have any voltage across it (0v, 100 V, -5,000 V, whatever) and still pass no current. An open circuit (or open switch) forces the current to zero, not the voltage.

If you want to force no voltage between two points, you need to connect a short circuit between them. That is, connect them with an ideal wire or an ideal closed switch.

> it should be ... 0V for V2, since there is a break in the circuit so it would be 0 anywhere.

V2 is connected across the battery. The battery (in this simple model) is an element that produces a fixed voltage across its terminals. The the voltmeter is measuring the voltage across the battery terminals, therefore it measures the emf of the battery.  (Later you'll learn that real batteries have "internal resistance" so that the voltage across their terminals is not strictly equal to their emf, but that's for another day)